# Java Gridbag missalign - last cell in second row displayed in first row

Tags: java, layout, gridbaglayout

I am using GB layout for a form. Currently there are two rows, each consisting of 6 elements (the first row features labels, the second text fields). My problem is that element that should display in X 5 Y 1 displays in X 6 Y 0. Could you please point me to the mistake I am making?

```
public GUI() {
    super("Bla");
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(layout);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();      
    [enter image description here][1]gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    Container con = getContentPane();

    panel1 = new JPanel();

    labBrawn = new JLabel("Brawn");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    con.add(labBrawn, gbc); 

    labAgility = new JLabel("Agility");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    con.add(labAgility, gbc);

    labIntellect = new JLabel("Intellect");
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    con.add(labIntellect, gbc);

    labCunning = new JLabel("Cunning");
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    con.add(labCunning, gbc);

    labWillpower = new JLabel("Willpower");
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    con.add(labWillpower, gbc);

    labPresence = new JLabel("Presence");
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    con.add(labPresence, gbc);



    txtBrawn = new JTextField("", 2);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    con.add(txtBrawn, gbc);

    txtAgility = new JTextField("", 2);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    con.add(txtAgility, gbc);

    txtIntellect = new JTextField("", 2);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    con.add(txtIntellect, gbc);

    txtCunning = new JTextField("", 2);
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    con.add(txtCunning, gbc);

    txtWillpower = new JTextField("", 2);
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    con.add(txtWillpower, gbc);

    txtPresence = new JTextField("", 2);
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    con.add(txtPresence);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GridBagLayout` you need to call

> add(Component component, Object constraints)

Adding your last component you forgot about `GridBagConstraints` object `con.add(txtPresence);`. Without it, component will be put after last component in first row, as it is first free space it will see being not constrained (it just makes Y=0 and goes for next available X). If you will be adding components in `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` without `GridBagConstraints` object, they will be put in one row.

Remember to set `weights`, `fill` and `anchor` with your `GridBagConstraints` object.

You can also see my [GridBagManager](https://github.com/bartlsntsk/GridBagManager) repo on github. It contains a demo showing how it works. You should still understand how `GridBagLayout` works though.

SSCCE: (quickfix of your code)

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setSize(600, 600);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            gui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public GUI() {
        super();

        //those should be initialized outside
        JLabel labBrawn = new JLabel("Brawn");
        JLabel labAgility = new JLabel("Agility");
        JLabel labIntellect = new JLabel("Intellect");
        JLabel labCunning = new JLabel("Cunning");
        JLabel labWillpower = new JLabel("Willpower");
        JLabel labPresence = new JLabel("Presence");

        JTextField txtBrawn = new JTextField("", 2);
        JTextField txtAgility = new JTextField("", 2);
        JTextField txtIntellect = new JTextField("", 2);
        JTextField txtCunning = new JTextField("", 2);
        JTextField txtWillpower = new JTextField("", 2);
        JTextField txtPresence = new JTextField("", 2);
        //--------------------------------------------

        //here goes actual GUI
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        JPanel dataInputPanel = new JPanel();
        dataInputPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        dataInputPanel.add(labBrawn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        dataInputPanel.add(labAgility, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        dataInputPanel.add(labIntellect, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        dataInputPanel.add(labCunning, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        dataInputPanel.add(labWillpower, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        dataInputPanel.add(labPresence, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        dataInputPanel.add(txtBrawn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        dataInputPanel.add(txtAgility, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        dataInputPanel.add(txtIntellect, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        dataInputPanel.add(txtCunning, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        dataInputPanel.add(txtWillpower, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        dataInputPanel.add(txtPresence, gbc);

        dataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.add(dataInputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my... Thanks a lot, sorry for bothering with such a question.

Comment: @Faire Yup, no problem. Happens to me all the time. That's why I created GridBagManager and my abstract panel have it's own `add()` method, which calls `add(comp,gbc)`, `GridBagConstraints gbc` being a field of this class. Simple as that. Look it up, happy coding!